# MySQL query using DISTINCT return one from many possible options

Tags: mysql

It was hard to come up with a good title for this one.  I have a query selecting products from my table.  Each product may belong to multiple categories.  So when I add in the 'category' to my DISTINCT query, it sometimes returns multiple of the same product because that product belongs to more than one category.  I want my query to just pick one of the categories and return that, doesn't matter which one.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ci.NAME, 
   ci.pid, 
   ci.description, 
   ci.price, 
   ci.saleprice, 
   ci.ingredients, 
   ci.allergens AS allergens, 
   ci.isfood, 
   ci.quantity, 
   ci.ismostpopular, 
   ci.activedate, 
   ci.isfrozen, 
   cc.NAME      AS category 
FROM   cart_category cc 
   JOIN cart_item_category cic 
     ON cc.id = cic.catid 
   JOIN cart_item ci 
     ON cic.itemref = ci.itemref 
WHERE  cc.active = 1 
   AND ci.active = 1 
   AND ci.isdeleted = 0 
   AND ci.isfrozen = 0 
   AND ( ci.NAME LIKE '%dark%' 
          OR ci.pid = '%dark%' ) 
   AND ci.quantity > 5 
   AND cc.NAME <> "nutritionals";
```

When I add in `cc.name as category` is when it returns multiple of the same product.

Answer (score 0):

try just to limit it:
    ... LIMIT 1

Comment: That will just return 1 product.  I need it to return all the products that match the search.

Comment: Replace join with subquery and LIMIT the subquery.

Comment: you can group by product id

Comment: grouping by product id appears to be producing the correct results, i will need to do more testing.  I'm assuming it just selects the first category it finds.